# Function $f$ not in $L^1$ but $\hat{f} \in L^1$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, fourier-analysis

Can you have a function $f \notin L^1$ but its Fourier transform $\hat{f} \in L^1$? Ive been playing around with examples and I cant find one, but I also cant prove one doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More on the example of @md2pepe.
Line 18 on this page below from a textbook says that the Fourier transform of
$\frac{W}{\pi}\operatorname{sinc}(Wt)$ is $\operatorname{rect}(\frac{\omega}{2W})$

[image: table]

I just Googled "table of fourier transforms" and took the first image.
This table by itself does not show what definition of Fourier transform is used.  That is, "where is the $2\pi$?"  Possibilities are
$$
\widehat{f}(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-j\omega t}f(t)\;dt
\\
\widehat{f}(\omega) = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-j\omega t}f(t)\;dt
\\
\widehat{f}(\omega) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-j\omega t}f(t)\;dt
\\
\widehat{f}(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-j 2\pi \omega t}f(t)\;dt
$$
and maybe more?

Comment: Please do [not use pictures for critical portions](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/20529/290189) of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not viewable to some, such as those who use screen readers. [Scanned pages from books are discouraged on SE network](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/155600/259305). The [Markdown syntax for tables](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/32850/290189) is recently available.

Comment: Edited to include the relevant information from the picture.

Comment: Downvote removed.

Answer (score 5):

For
$$
f(x) = \frac{\sin x}{x} \not\in L^1(\mathbb{R})
$$
one has
$$
\hat{f}(\xi) = C \chi_{[-a,a]}(\xi) \in L^1(\mathbb{R})
$$
where $C$ and $a$ are some constants depending on the exact choice of definition of Fourier transform.

Comment: sorry, what is a?

Comment: Some value $>0$. The exact result might depend on how the Fourier transform is defined. There are a few definitions used.

Comment: I suspect he meant $\big(\sin(ax)\big)/x. \qquad$

Comment: @md2perpe : In its present form, your answer cannot be right because your definition of $f(x)$ does not mention anything called $a. \qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy. I mean that $a$ is some value which depends on what definition of Fourier transform is used. The reason that I write $\sim$ instead of $=$ is the same.

Comment: Description of constants added.